# Why has my WebAPK "Add to homescreen" suddenly stopped working and gives a white screen?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, homescreen

I have a very simple "Add to homescreen" tool for mobile browsers so they can add a website to there mobile homescreen.

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "Voetbal",
  "name": "Voetbalpoule",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/voetbal/icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/voetbal/icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/voetbal/?source=app2homescreen",
  "background_color": "#ED008C",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/voetbal/",
  "theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

service-worker.js

```
/*
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", ev => { 
  // Stop Chrome from asking _now_
  ev.preventDefault();

  // Create your custom "add to home screen" button here if needed.
  // Keep in mind that this event may be called multiple times, 
  // so avoid creating multiple buttons!
  myCustomButton.onclick = () => ev.prompt();
});
*/
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
```

This has worked fine for months but the last few days I heard from users that they get a white screen after clicking the icon from the homescreen.

I have reproduce this myself and indeed, when I delete this button from my homescreen and go with Chrome to the website I get the "Add to homescreen" button at the bottom of my screen.
I add this and then I go to my homescreen and click on this button, than I get a white screen .........

This has worked fine till the last few days so has there been an update from Google?

Any idea why I get a white screen?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I found out that a PHP script error was creating this white screen so it was not WebAPK that was giving the problem but a PHP type error.